# How to get the status of the backup database running through dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have inherited a SQL Server job that runs a stored procedure which has dynamic SQL queries in it.

Example:

```
SET @statement = 'use master
                  ALTER DATABASE '+@database+' SET RECOVERY simple;
                  BACKUP DATABASE '+@database+'
                  TO DISK = ''xyz\'+@database+'.bak''
                  WITH INIT, COMPRESSION
                  WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:10'';
                  ALTER DATABASE '+@database+'SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
                  DROP DATABASE '+@database+';'

EXEC (@statement);
```

If I understand correctly, the waitfor delay was added to make sure that the backup is complete before altering the database. However, that is where I am getting confused.

My questions are:

1. Will the query jump to/execute Alter database command even when the backup transaction is in process?
2. How do I make the query wait until the backup is complete.

I tried to search resources to understand this but could not find any. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The execution is synchronous. No step in your execution will occur until the prior one is completed, so the `WAITFOR` will occur once the backup is completed and the second `ALTER` will occur after that.